# how to Add two or more time datatype in different column on same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a datatype (time) named lap1,lap2 and lap3 as an attribute in a table called race.

```
lap1         lap2        lap3
1:20:20      1:30:40     1:50:20
2:30:15      2:12:32     1:21:30
```

I want to add the lap1,lap2 and lap3. i have tried doing this (lap1+lap2+lap3). But it is not giving me a correct time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use addtime(tim1,time2)

```
SELECT ADDTIME(ADDTIME(lap1,lap2),lap3) as required_datetime from race;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ADDTIME(ADDTIME(lap1,lap2),lap3) as required_date from race;
```